# Running Macro on a WokSheet of Excel

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, excel-formula

I am able to create a excel from Python win32com ,so i know all the details of excel viz. Total number or rows , columns , Worksheet Names and location where it is saved. Now i want to run some application which can run a macro on a worksheet of created excel .

Example of macro :

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlPie
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("C2:C6")
End Sub
```

Please tell which application can do this .

Answer (score 0):

Well as you are probably aware, a little bit of work might be involved, but xlwings should be right up your street. For example from within VBA we can import functions by calling Python. From the docs:

```
Sub MyMacro()
    RunPython ("import mymodule; mymodule.rand_numbers()")
End Sub

#which will run the following or any required, saved function.

import numpy as np
from xlwings import Workbook, Range

def rand_numbers():
    wb = Workbook.caller()  # Creates a reference to the calling Excel file
    n = Range('Sheet1', 'B1').value  # Write desired dimensions into Cell B1
    rand_num = np.random.randn(n, n)
    Range('Sheet1', 'C3').value = rand_num
```

Enjoy, http://xlwings.org/